# Cannot associate an asset with blob

Tags: azure, go, azure-media-services

I am trying to upload a video to azure media services, but once i create the asset and then upload the video to blob with the SAS url, the asset does not contain the video.

main.go

```golang
func main() {
    assetName := "sample1"
    asset, err := azureMedia.CreateAsset(assetName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println("Asset Name: ", *asset.Name)

    sasURL, err := azureMedia.GetStorageURLForAsset(assetName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(sasURL)

    err = storage.UploadToBlobFromSASUrl(sasURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return
}
```

media_services.go

```golang
func CreateAsset(assetName string) (*media.Asset, error) {
    asset, err := assetsClient.CreateOrUpdate(context.Background(), resourceGroupName, accountName, assetName, media.Asset{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return &asset, nil
}

func GetStorageURLForAsset(assetName string) (string, error) {
    result, err := assetsClient.ListContainerSas(context.Background(), resourceGroupName, accountName, assetName, media.ListContainerSasInput{
        ExpiryTime:  &date.Time{Time: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 4).UTC()},
        Permissions: media.ReadWrite,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return (*result.AssetContainerSasUrls)[0], nil
}
```

storage.go

```golang
func UploadToBlobFromSASUrl(sasUrl string) error {
    // When someone receives the URL, they access the SAS-protected resource with code like this:
    u, err := url.Parse(sasUrl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    containerURL := azblob.NewContainerURL(*u, azblob.NewPipeline(azblob.NewAnonymousCredential(), azblob.PipelineOptions{}))

    blockBlobUrl := containerURL.NewBlockBlobURL("sample.mp4")

    video, err := os.Open("./sample_videos/sample1.mp4")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    resp, err := blockBlobUrl.Upload(context.Background(), video, azblob.BlobHTTPHeaders{}, azblob.Metadata{}, azblob.BlobAccessConditions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _, err = buf.ReadFrom(resp.Response().Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    newStr := buf.String()

    log.Println(resp.Status(), resp.StatusCode(), newStr)

    return nil
}
```

From what i understood from the docs, the asset should be present and be associated with the video blob, but when i tried to encode it, it says there is no file associated with the asset.

Is there something I'm missing? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Side note: don't abuse `panic`. In `main` use `log.Fatal`, outside of `main` return non-nil `error` values or handle the error.

Comment: Possibly relevant: Don't ignore the error return from `bytes.Buffer.ReadFrom` (and in general, don't directly call `ReadFrom` or `WriteTo` where an `io.Copy` will do; among other things, it allows you to change/switch out your `io.Reader`/`io.Writer` easier). (Also, make sure you close `resp.Body()`.)

Comment: Thank you for the tips, will keep that in mind. I'm just messing around with media services to get a clearer idea of how it works. That's why i used ```panic```.

Comment: ```buf.ReadFrom``` returns a nil error. The video is being uploaded to blob, that works fine but it's not being reflected on the asset. Do you have any other suggestions @DaveC